# What happens before the Crippled God?

Tags: malazan, steven-erikson

I was planning to reread the last two Malazan books before the release of the Crippled God, but the date seemed to appear out of thin air. So what should I remember before starting the Crippled God?

PS: I don't want full summaries, just little points in the form of (hypothetical example) `Ganeos Paran killed by Mel`.

EDIT1: To clarify further, what I meant to ask is what each character was doing and where he was just before the start of the crippled god. Actually I have started reading the book, and most of the characters were covered in the first chapter in such a manner that made things clear. Still, I found some parts disconcerting like **Ganeos'**, since I couldn't figure out where he was from the text. So a good answer would have been 'Ganeos was in Aren, defying the emperor and besieged by X and Y'.

The problem arises because most reviews don't go over the story in detail to avoid spoilers, and the wiki pages for the series are seriously outdated and incomplete.

Comment: Do you just want things from *Toll the Hounds* and *Dust of Dreams* or do you want a summary of the whole series? (That's an awful lot).

Comment: Just the most recent part that has an effect. I remember most of the general things, but I have forgotten some things like where **Ganeos** is supposed to be at the beginning of the book etc. For example : I don't want details of the __Forkrul__ part, just that there was some mass migration and that the __Forkrul__ were not as invincible as everyone thought.

Comment: Couple of suggestions: "and I have been blindsided."  I'm not quite sure how or why you were "blindsided", you may want to clear that up.  The question is kind of broad and subjective, if you could add some more specific detail I think that might help you get the answer your looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I remember :

- Karsa joined by his daughters
- Tavore and her company almost destroyed a battle with the K'Chain.
- The Wolf Company marching towards the Crippled God
- The elder gods stirring to fight against the new ones

Definitely leaves a lot to be desired.

EDIT: Other things that I remembered after reading the last book -

- There's a weird procession of children in a desert somewhere, which is being attacked by the Assail.
- Toc's dead, so are the Awl except for one called Torrent.
- Onos Toolan died again due to Barghast stupidity, and so did Hetan.
- Mappo joined with some members of the travelling guild out of Darujhistan, and was stuck somewhere on Letherii, alongwith Torrent and Hetan's children.
- There's infighting in the wolf camp.